# Loopback 3 current date time

Tags: mysql, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have the model now i want to insert the current date and time, but the time is not proper. I am using the mysql database.
Here is my model

"message": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "inserted_date": {
      "type": "date",
      "dataType": "timestamp",
    "defaultFn": "now"
    }

and am getting the inserted date and time as 2019-03-05T04:48:05.541Z. I want to get the current date and time. Can anyone help me how to do this.

Comment: Show the code? Show the SQL! Show the table structure - can't tell from your JSON what is a table/row or column. `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` is a good way to present it unambigiously in SO. What is a "now date and time"?

Comment: i mean to say i want to get the inserted date and time like current timestamp.

Comment: Note that the time stamp includes the time zone designation `Z`, meaning 'Zulu Time' or UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, often called GMT or Greenwich Mean Time).  If you're in a different time zone, then you need to apply the appropriate time zone offset to come up with your local time.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler i need the date and time to be like this 2019-03-05 09:45:18. how to do this

Comment: Control the formatting in your application, or when retrieving the data. date types don't have a format and its efficient for sorting/ordering that way.

Comment: @danblack how to format can give me an example

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler is there any conversion from Zulu Time to GMT using javascript or jquery